# javascript dynamically creating script block

Tags: javascript, client-side

I have a question about inserting a dynamically created script with JavaScript.

This is the code I'm using:

```
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'code.js';
  body.appendChild(script);
```

I usually place scripts at the bottom of the page, but if it's dynamically inserted like this, is there a way to ensure that the script is placed at the bottom of the page?

Comment: How about placing it on `DOMContentLoaded`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that.  Could you explain?

Comment: At the time that `body.appendChild(script)` is executed, that *will* be the bottom of the page. Can you clarify then what you mean?

Comment: Crescent Fresh, what do you mean?  Are you saying that body.appendChild() is already inserting scripts to the bottom page.

Comment: @JaPerk14: It's an event. Like `load`, except it only waits for the DOM to load, not all content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If it's dynamically inserted like this, is there a way to ensure that the script is placed at the bottom of the page?

You already do that with `body.appendChild(script)`; of course there might be other elements inserted after it later on.

However, as you are dynamically inserting the script, there is absolutely no need to *ensure* placing it at any certain location - it is loaded and executed asynchronously (neither blocking something nor waiting for something). You may place it *anywhere* in the document, and even remove it right away, it will not influence any load or execute behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to ensure that using Jquery. The `code.js` will be called after DOM is loaded and putted right before `</body>` tag:

```
$(function() {
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'code.js';
  body.appendChild(script);
});
```